# Rails s3: Upload objects in a specific path depending on the ID of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I have a model called "CourseObjects", it belongs to another model called "Courses".

Each course has objects (video, pdf, office files, etc). I am uploading these elements to S3 from a form of the "CourseObjects" model, at the moment everything is ok. How do I create a path in s3 that for each "courseObject" that the user is uploading, is saved in the specific id of each course?

```
 class CourseObject < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :course


    has_attached_file :file,:storage => :s3,:bucket => 'demo-files',
                                             :path => "/capacitation/course_objects/(COURSE_ID)/content/:filename",
                                             :s3_credentials => {
                                                 :access_key_id => 'key',
                                                 :secret_access_key => 'secret_key'
                                             }

    validates_attachment_content_type :file,
                                                                        content_type: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif', 'video/mp4', 'application/pdf', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation', :pptx]

end
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveStorage manages the naming of blobs (what gets stashed in s3) for its own purposes, but you can set `filename` metadata when you attach a file; you can then  use/search for it later.

If you have set up s3 storage globally (`config/storage.yml`), you don't need to declare the service again with `has_attached_file` unless you are overriding the default storage medium for the environment.

```rb
class CourseObject < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :course

    has_attached_file :file
end
```

Then wherever you are attaching the file:

```rb
# 'file' is an IO object, UploadedFile, direct upload ref or whatever.
course_obj.attach(file,     
                  filename: "/foo/#{course_obj.course.id}/bar/#{name}")
```